# Game Over image not showing

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.8

I am making a spaceship game where you control a spaceship and fire bullets at the enemies. I am now trying to make a game over background show when the player and any enemy collide, but when I ran the game, the game over background never showed!

This is my current code (Some parts omitted or replaced by *--snip--*):

```
class Spaceship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, s, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screen = s
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.image = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (175, 175))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, s, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screen = s
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (100, 100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

    def update(self):
        self.y -= 5
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
        if self.y < 0:
            self.kill()


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, s, x, y, t):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.type = t
        self.screen, self.x, self.y = s, x, y
        self.image = pygame.image.load("enemy.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (235, 215))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
        self.score_given = get_enemy_given_score()[self.type]

    def update(self):
        if self.y < 0:
            self.kill()
        self.y += 3
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)


class GameOverBackground(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, s, x, y, size=(100, 100)):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screen, self.x, self.y = s, x, y
        self.size = size
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Game_Over.jpg")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, self.size)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


bg = GameOverBackground(screen, 0, 0)

spaceship = Spaceship(screen, 400, 400)

bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

enemy_interval = 2000  # It's in milliseconds
enemy_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(enemy_event, enemy_interval)

score = 0

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 30)
textsurface = font.render("Score: {:,}".format(score), True, (0, 0, 0))

spaceship_collided = False

running = True
while running:
    --snip--

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))  # DO NOT DRAW ANYTHING IN FRONT OF THIS LINE, I'M WARNING YOU

    bullets.update()

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    amount = 5

    if key[pygame.K_a]:
        spaceship.x -= amount
    --snip--

    spaceship.update()

    if not spaceship_collided:
        screen.blit(spaceship.image, spaceship.rect)

    if spaceship_collided is False:
        bullets.draw(screen)
        enemies.draw(screen)

        for i in enemies:
            i.update()
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(i, bullets, True):
                score += i.score_given
                i.kill()

    if score >= 99999:
        score = 99999

    textsurface = font.render("Score: {:,}".format(score), True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(textsurface, (590, 0))

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(spaceship, enemies, dokill=True):
        spaceship_collided = True
        bg.blitme()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition `pygame.sprite.spritecollide(spaceship, enemies, dokill=True):` os only fulfilled in a single frame. If you want to permanently display the game over screen, you need to draw it depending on the `spaceship_collided` :

```py
running = True
while running:
    # [...]

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(spaceship, enemies, dokill=True):
        spaceship_collided = True
    if spaceship_collided:
        bg.blitme()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```